# How to store sensitive data inside node env variable?

Tags: node.js

I don't want my database link,aws key and other details to be exposed , so that I am thinking of storing them inside node env variables. But I don't know how can I achieve that. Or is there any better way to achieve high security for suck kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) is a popular choice for allowing access with better security than environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for telling me this. I was going through npm vault and tried to find out tutorial regarding that for nodejs/expressjs implementation. But I did not find it. So can you suggest me some good tutorial?

Comment: Just use the API (https://www.vaultproject.io/api/) using your favorite http client (axios, superagent, etc).